# stylus: add styling to an id that is generated in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui, stylus

I have a `jquery` [datepicker widget](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) that I'm using, and I want to overwrite the CSS associated with its `input` field.

Unfortunately, it looks like the `id` for that field is generated dynamically on page load:

```
<input type="text" id="dp1382434269539" style="position: absolute; top: 372.9375px; width: 0px; left: 579.8125px;">
```

We're using stylus and I'd like to be able to style any `input` that has and `id` that begins with "dp" -- is there an easy way to select an `id` this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [attribute selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp) for this. An example would be:

```
input[id^="dp"] {
    /* your styling */
}
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/DAC84/jmHUr/)